# Python timedelta object with negative values

Tags: python, python-datetime

I don't quite understand how negative arguments in `datetime.timedelta` are interpreted.

With Positive values:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(days=1,seconds=1,microseconds=1,milliseconds=1,minutes=1,hours=1,weeks=1)
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
>>> (8, 3661, 1001)
```

This is pretty straightforward. A similar example with negative values looks like:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(days=-1,seconds=-1,microseconds=-1,milliseconds=-1,minutes=-1,hours=-1,weeks=-1)
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
>>> (-9, 82738, 998999)
```

As per my understanding seconds and microseconds are derived like:

- seconds = `86399 - (-60-3600-1)`
- microseconds = `999999 - (-1-1000)`

Is this correct? How come days equals -9?

I am reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) section of docs. But still don't quite understand the working with negative values. Please share explanations or relevant documentation links. Thanks :)

Comment: It's much easier to read (and make sense of) `timedelta` calls if you use named arguments btw...

Comment: Agreed and edited

Comment: For printing `datetime.timedelta`s, this looks more like what most users expect imho: `str(td) if td >= datetime.timedelta() else f"-{-td}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes complete sense, `(-1 week + -1 day) + (-1 hours) + (-1 minutes) + (-1 seconds) + (-1 milliseconds) + (-1 microseconds)` equals to:    `(-8 days) + (-1 hours) + (-1 minutes) + (-1 seconds) + (-1 milliseconds) + (-1 microseconds)`

By having less than -8 days, with -1 hours, -1 minutes, ... the number of days will have to be even less than -8 to make the negative hours, minutes, seconds... into positive hours, minutes, seconds....(since only days can be represented negatively, others,such as seconds, are always represented positively). Which means that days will have to be -9.

If you print `d` , you will get `-9 days 22:58:58.998999`, with negative 9 days and positive 22+ hours. Seeing the `str` of the `timedelta` could help you have better understanding of how negative `timedelta` is represented.

Comment: the resultant number of days are -8, but due to negative hours, mins, secs... the days become -9. So everytime days are decremented by 1 if there are negative hours, mins secs? What if some of the arguments are non-negative?

Comment: Imagine the timedelta is on a number line that has an increment of one day, if the days itself is negative -8, and and the decimals are still negative, the days will bounce to the next left whole, since only days can be negative. If the days is -8, and others (not including weeks) or the sum of others are positive, then days will remain -8. `timedelta(days=-1, seconds=1, weeks=-1)` the number of days would remain -8, as there’s a positive second, `timedelta(days=-1, minutes=1, seconds=-1, weeks=-1)` the number of days is still -8 because the sum of 1 minute and -1 second is positive 59 minutes

Answer (score 7):

Because of the way timedeltas are stored internally, **only the `days` attribute can take on negative values**. This can be surprising when the timedelta is printed back. An [illuminating example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/datetime-timedelta.html),

```
>>> d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
(-1, 86399, 999999)
```

ie. -1d + 86399s + 999999µs = -1µs

Comment: the `datetime` package is so badly designed..