# What is the difference between Django timezone now and the built-in one?

Tags: python, django

I've just noticed this:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import timezone

>>> (datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc) - timezone.now()).microseconds
999989

>>> (datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc) - timezone.now()).seconds
86399

>>> 24*60*60
86400

>>> (datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc) - timezone.now()).days
-1

>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 17, 13, 1, 36, 913132, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 17, 13, 1, 41, 913958, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

How do both options to get the current time with the UTC "timezone" differ? Why is the difference a positive number of seconds, but exactly negative one day?

Can I replace `timezone.now()` by `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value in your subtraction is getting created a microsecond or so after the first value. So it's a later point in time. You're subtracting the later point in time from the earlier point in time. Yielding a negative delta:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc) - timezone.now()
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86399, microseconds=999981)
```

If you're only looking at the day or microsecond part of that, it looks like a huge difference. But this is simply the way a `timedelta` represents a fraction of a second *in the past*. It's *minus one day **plus** 86399 seconds and 999981 ms*. See [Python timedelta object with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803405/476).

Comment: So the django one and the builtin are the same / behave the same, even if used together?

Comment: Yes, `timezone.now` is just a convenience wrapper to simplify constructing a valid aware `datetime` with Django's timezone settings.